# Why does Doubleclick get added to my page (sometimes) when I use Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, doubleclick-ad-exchange

I have a website that I manage myself on a VPS, so in theory everything should be under my control. I have no advertising whatsoever -- in fact, the only external script I run is for Google Analytics:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'XXXXXXXXX', 'YYYYYYYY');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I use Ghostery in my browser to tell me what scripts are running on what pages. Fine. Accessing my own page, usually, shows exactly one result: Google Analytics. Except *sometimes*, it will display two results, Google Analytics and Doubleclick. This does not appear to be URL dependent: refreshing a single page will sometimes show Doubleclick, and sometimes not.

It is not malware related: I experience this on all of my devices, as do my users (who in fact reported this to me, prompting me to install Ghostery).

Why is this happening?

Comment: Doubleclick appears when you use the demographics feature (ie. ga('require','displayfeatures')).

Comment: Interesting! I'm curious why it only rarely appears then. Perhaps GA only collects demographic information on a random sampling of visitors? In any case, your comment sounds like a good answer, so if you post it as such I can accept it.

Comment: Everyone says this but I do not use those options and it is still there.
Only sometimes so I can go from a 280ms load to a 1.6s load from this single intrusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubleclick appears when you use the demographics feature (ie. ga('require','displayfeatures')).